# AWS API Gateway create API key from lambda for unique user : Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-key, aws-sdk-js

I want to create a unique api key whenever a user logs into my website

I want to do this from AWS Lambda based on a trigger

I plan to do this through the RESTAPI via axios

I believe I have misunderstood the docs, It's just killing me as my submission is just around the corner

inside the function

```
    var x = await axios.post('/apikeys',{
    name : "aaaaaa",
    description : "Strinaaaag",
    enabled : true,
    generateDistinctId : true,
    value : "sasdasdasdasdsd",
    stageKeys : [ {
      restApiId : "Strissng",
      stageName : "prod"
    } ],
  })
```

and this is not working even the one below

```js
params = {
        name : "aaaaaa",
        description : "Strinaaaag",
        enabled : true,
        generateDistinctId : true,
        value : "sasdasdasdasdsd",
        stageKeys : [ {
          restApiId : "Strissng",
          stageName : "prod"
        } ],
      }

AWS.APIGateway().createApiKey(params,function(err,data){
........
})
```

Comment: Why not use Signed Cookies?

Comment: The user will communicate in any form, it's just a RESTapi, designing for voice assistants, so there will not be browsers in place

I want API Gateway to restrict  based on the API keys so that will not get any false call -  Which I do not want to be billed